# How to add an image to a Drawable Resource File

Tags: java, android, xml

I have created a drawable resource file and all I need is to add an image to this drawable resource file that contains layer list which this layer list contains an item and shape like this example
resoucedrawablefile.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>


        <bitmap android:gravity="center" android:src="@drawable/remove" />

    </item>

    <!-- Drop Shadow Stack -->
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="2dp" android:left="1dp" />
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
            <solid android:color="#00CCCCCC" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="2dp" android:left="1dp" />
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
            <solid android:color="#10CCCCCC" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="2dp" android:left="1dp" />
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
            <solid android:color="#20CCCCCC" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="2dp" android:left="1dp" />
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
            <solid android:color="#30CCCCCC" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="2dp" android:left="1dp" />
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
            <solid android:color="#50CCCCCC" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- Background -->
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#b5e40008" />
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: you can add the image using bitmap tag in item tag. check it. Accept and upvote if it helps your need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add like below.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list>

        <item>
            <shape>
                <solid android:color="#000000"/>
                <padding android:right="#000000"/>
            </shape>
        </item>

        <item>


            <bitmap android:gravity="right|center" android:src="@drawable/down_arrow" />

        </item>

    </layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/image" />

    <!-- Drop Shadow Stack -->
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="2dp" android:left="1dp" />
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
            <solid android:color="#00CCCCCC" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="2dp" android:left="1dp" />
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
            <solid android:color="#10CCCCCC" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="2dp" android:left="1dp" />
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
            <solid android:color="#20CCCCCC" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="2dp" android:left="1dp" />
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
            <solid android:color="#30CCCCCC" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="2dp" android:left="1dp" />
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
            <solid android:color="#50CCCCCC" />
        </shape>
    </item>


</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <!-- adding image -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/image_name_here" />
<!-- Drop Shadow Stack -->
<item>
    <shape>
        <padding android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="2dp" android:left="1dp" />
        <corners android:radius="10dp" />
        <solid android:color="#00CCCCCC" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape>
        <padding android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="2dp" android:left="1dp" />
        <corners android:radius="10dp" />
        <solid android:color="#10CCCCCC" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape>
        <padding android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="2dp" android:left="1dp" />
        <corners android:radius="10dp" />
        <solid android:color="#20CCCCCC" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape>
        <padding android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="2dp" android:left="1dp" />
        <corners android:radius="10dp" />
        <solid android:color="#30CCCCCC" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape>
        <padding android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="2dp" android:left="1dp" />
        <corners android:radius="10dp" />
        <solid android:color="#50CCCCCC" />
    </shape>
</item>

<!-- Background -->
<item>
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#b5e40008" /><corners android:radius="10dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```